# What is the difference of the different ways of importing libraries in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I struggle quite a bit with using external libraries with typescript. I very much would like to add custom typings for the libraries that do not have typings available, and I struggle with understanding how imports and requires work with typings.

What is the difference, and how does a corresponding typing look for the following situations:

`import something = require('something');`

`import * as something from 'something';`

`const something = require('something');`

`import {something} from 'something';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is the "old" way of importing external modules and the `import` syntax is the current recommended way which is aligned with the ES6 syntax. Depending on the `module` configured in `tsconfig.json` TypeScript will transpile this syntax to the relevant module type/style.

If you want to learn how TypeScript resolves external modules (it supports two modes `node` and `classic` - configurable in `tsconfig.json` as `moduleResolution`) have a read through the documentation here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html . The main difference is around how non-relative module paths are resolved.

If you want to learn about how and where TypeScript looks for typings (type declarations) have a read of this blog post: http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript/. From the blog - it will:

1. Try `module.d.ts` next to `module.js` for custom code
2. Try checking for a `typings:` in `packages.json` for node modules (in `node_modules`)
3. Try looking for any ambient declarations (`declare module X` syntax) across the bundle of files it's processing when `tsconfig.json` is present. This is important, because the presence of that files makes TypeScript process all included files as a single "project"/"workspace"
4. Look for tripple-slash comments `/// <reference path="path/to/declarations.d.ts" />` - I don't recommend this any more given that a `tsconfig.json` project file can be used.

You also have two type of typings:

1. External module typings - live next to the file or in the case of node modules a path to them exists in `typings:` in `project.json`. Syntax is `export X` without a module declaration (file is a module!). Think in terms of them being "bound" to the code file and something like "This is what this module looks like"
2. Ambient typings - live anywhere. Syntax is `declare module X`. Think in terms of "There exists a type/module X somewhere and this is what it looks like". For modules TypeScript will match based on module name. Other use case is global variables (e.g. jQuery's `$`).

The documentation for what and how can be configured in `tsconfig.json` have a read here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

In regards to the different examples that you gave - let's say you have a module called `moduleA`. One thing to note is that a file is a module in JS/TS world, so:

**moduleA.ts**

```
export class Car
{
    public model: string = "";
}
```

**moduleA.js - transpiled (target ES5 and module type CommonJS)**

```
"use strict";
var Car = (function () {
    function Car() {
        this.model = "";
    }
    return Car;
}());
exports.Car = Car;
```

**main.ts**

```
import moduleA = require("./moduleA");

new moduleA.Car();

// equivalent to the above - import everything under myModuleName
import * as myModuleName from './moduleA';

new myModuleName.Car();

// import only the Car class
import {Car} from './moduleA'

new Car();

// import only the Car class and alias it as MyCar
import {Car as MyCar} from './moduleA'

new MyCar();
```

**main.js - transpiled (target ES5 and module type CommonJS)**

```
"use strict";
var moduleA = require("./moduleA");
new moduleA.Car();

// equivalent to the above - import everything under myModuleName
var myModuleName = require('./moduleA');
new myModuleName.Car();

// import only the Car class
var moduleA_1 = require('./moduleA');
new moduleA_1.Car();

// import only the Car class and alias it as MyCar
var moduleA_2 = require('./moduleA');
new moduleA_2.Car();
```